# Can errors creep into javascript when using it as an input from multiple computers?

Tags: javascript

We have a very strange thing happening at work.  We are using javascript in a lengthy question and answer session.  As this is done, a large data set is loaded with information and, when all is completed, the data is sent to our servers.

The error that we see (and it is random) is that some of the variables are not set.  They are set to the default zero.  The problem is that there is no way that the user can progress through the menu selection to the final page without selecting options.  There is not a way that they can be the zero default.  Yet they are.

So either someone (or some ones) is/are messing with us and they have written their own script to do this; or the cause of this is that the system is being overloaded and, because of the volume of hits we get, we have extended beyond the capacity of javascript.  All programs have limitations. Even computing languages and scripting languages are written by people.  So they must have flaws because all software has flaws.  Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I'm thinking *'they have written their own script...'* is the most realistic reason.  If they really wanted to, they could probably use a web browser's console to 'fix' their data the way they wanted it, as well.

Comment: Or, the more likely scenario, there's a bug in your application code

Comment: It is highly unlikely there are bugs in javascript engines causing such nondeterministic behavior. More likely, there are bugs in your code that you are just yet unaware of. It also could be that users alter the internal state of the app with browser integrated dev consoles.

Comment: I have ruled out any bug in our application code.  The data packet is never overwritten in the back end.  But there is more.  I have extensively tested the code with automated test software using selenium. All combinations I have tried does not produce the error.  I believe the suggestions here that people are using some sort of system to fix their data is the most likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it sounds like you have one of two problems (or both).

1. There is an error in your JavaScript.   "Not possible" is really "We tested it and we don't think this can happen, but it really can."
2. You are trusting the client side to validate all the correct information is sent.  Actually, it sounds like you really have this problem whether or not this is the culprit.  An attacker doesn't have to use your client or your JavaScript to post information to the server.  All you need is a client that can send data to a server: e.g. [Curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or a custom application.  This is a trivial attack to perform and is why you should never implicitly trust anything from the client without validating it first.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a limitation of your current knowledge.

From what you tell, it's safe to assume that you have no server side control of the form. That's bad.

In the server, if the form doesn't suit the expected range of values (the ones allowed in the client), you should either send the user back to square 1 or ban his ip address.

Comment: This is a good answer.  The other answer is good too.  I cannot pick which one I like best.